# How to manupulate JSON data for a List of a List in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a `JSON` data object which I am retrieving  from `mongoDB`. It has the following format:

```
var billData = [{
    "_id": "PT155/454",
    "_class": "com.aventyn.hms.domain.OPDBill",
    "billingDate": "2017-11-20",
    "patientId": "PT155",
    "transactions": [{
        "txnId": "PT155/454/1",
        "toBePaid": "0",
        "txnAmount": "0",
        "due": "0",
        "selfPay": true
    }, {
        "txnId": "PT155/454/2",
        "toBePaid": "450",
        "txnAmount": "350",
        "due": "100",
        "selfPay": false
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "PT156/455",
    "_class": "com.aventyn.hms.domain.OPDBill",
    "billingDate": "2017-11-20",
    "patientId": "PT156",
    "transactions": [{
        "txnId": "PT156/455/1",
        "toBePaid": "300",
        "txnAmount": "200",
        "due": "100",
        "selfPay": true
    }, {
        "txnId": "PT156/455/2",
        "toBePaid": "100",
        "txnAmount": "50",
        "due": "50",
        "selfPay": true
    }]
}];
```

My **problem** is I want to remove those transactions which have property of `selfPay: false` for this I am doing the following but It is not working:

```
$.each(billData, function (k, v) {
    $.each(v.transactions, function (tK, tV) {
        if (tV.selfPay == true) {
            billData[k].transactions = tV;
        }
    });
});
```

But the data which I get is same as what I am getting from the database.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks for your Help.

Link for jsfiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/0uy38pLf/

Comment: `v.transaction` should be `v.transactions`, no?

Comment: yes it is v.transactions, it was just a typing mistake while typing for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve the desired results (without even using any method of jQuery):

```js
var billData = [{
    "_id": "PT155/454",
    "_class": "com.aventyn.hms.domain.OPDBill",
    "billingDate": "2017-11-20",
    "patientId": "PT155",
    "transactions": [{
        "txnId": "PT155/454/1",
        "toBePaid": "0",
        "txnAmount": "0",
        "due": "0",
        "selfPay": true
      },
      {
        "txnId": "PT155/454/2",
        "toBePaid": "450",
        "txnAmount": "350",
        "due": "100",
        "selfPay": false
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "_id": "PT156/455",
    "_class": "com.aventyn.hms.domain.OPDBill",
    "billingDate": "2017-11-20",
    "patientId": "PT156",
    "transactions": [{
        "txnId": "PT156/455/1",
        "toBePaid": "300",
        "txnAmount": "200",
        "due": "100",
        "selfPay": true
      },
      {
        "txnId": "PT156/455/2",
        "toBePaid": "100",
        "txnAmount": "50",
        "due": "50",
        "selfPay": true
      }

    ]
  }
];

var result = billData.map(bill => {
  bill.transactions = bill.transactions.filter(tran => tran.selfPay);
  return bill;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you this one helps a lot.. can you tell if I have to check 2 condition then how to write like in if we use && or || operator to check different condition, can we do this here also

Comment: @VipulSingh -- yes you can. `.filter()`'s callback should return a boolean expression to include item in the result.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, it could be better, you negate the if clause. So that you check against `selfPay === false`.

```
console.log(billData);
$.each(billData,function(k,v){
    $.each(v.transactions,function(tK,tV){
        if(tV.selfPay === false ){
            billData[k].transactions.splice(tK, 1);
        }
    });
});
console.log(billData)
```

Also I guess you want to remove just that single item. To remove a single item use the `splice` function which takes the index of the item you want to remove in this case `tK`.

Hope it helps!